# Using replace() to remove full sentences from text data in Python

Tags: python, pandas, text, replace, str-replace

I am trying to remove three sentences from paragraphs of text data. I have a pandas dataframe with rows of paragraphs that I want to remove the same three sentences from. For example,

```
import pandas as pd

df_1 = pd.DataFrame({"text": ["the dog is red. He goes outside and runs.", 
                              "i like dogs because they are fun. i don't like that dogs bark at mailmen", 
                              "dogs bark at mailmen and i think its funny."]})
    
custom_stopwords = ["the dog is red", "i like dogs", "dogs bark at mailmen"]
 
for i in custom_stopwords: 
    df_1['text'] = df_1['text'].str.replace(i, '')
```

This method is working in this example I have provided, but it does not work on my actual data. The data I have is quite large, but I don't see why that would matter in this case. What is happening is some of my sentences will be removed and others will not. For example, I am unable to remove the word "installation(s)" without blocking out the parentheses with "/".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pandas.Series.str.replace` has a default keyword argument of `regex=True` which means it assumes the replacements are regular expressions (like your "installation(s)" could be interpreted). You're trying to replace string literals (or non-regular expressions at the very least). Adding `regex=False` should work fine:

```
for i in custom_stopwords: 
    df_1['text'] = df_1['text'].str.replace(i, '', regex=False)
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked perfectly! I wish I had asked sooner rather than spinning my wheels for...hours!

Answer (score 1):

Use `str.replace` with the argument `regex=False`. `(s)` is interpreted as a regular expression group, in this specific case equal to the character `s`.

Comment: Thank you, that worked perfectly!